# How to change Html table to Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

[image]

I am new in html.
I am sharing my html code that get `Json` data from server and show in a Html-table format.

Can you change my html code such that it will have a 
`button` between Video Link and Video Image and when I click on that button it play respective youtube video with  video id of the same row.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<script>

    $(function() {


   var people = [];

   $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/hy7g0', function(data) {
       $.each(data.videoLectureListing, function(i, f) {
          var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.Id + "</td>" +
           "<td>" + f.videoName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.date + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.time + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.video + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.image + "</td>" +
           "<td>" + f.videoDuration + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.liveStatus + "</td>" + "<td>"+ "</tr>"
           $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
     });

   });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="profile">
   <table id= "userdata" border="25">
  <thead>
            <th>ID</th> 
            <th>VIDEO NAME</th>
            <th>DATE</th>
            <th>TIME</th>
   <th>VIDEO LINK</th>
   <th>VIDEO IMAGE</th>
            <th>DURACTION</th>
            <th>LIVE STATUS</th>
        </thead>
      <tbody>

       </tbody>
   </table>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

i try a lot on internet but could not find anything about it please take it seriously and help me.Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are not a code writing service and so no, we won't just update your code to make it do what you want it to do. We ask that you do your research and make an attempt at a solution before posting here and then, if you do post, post a ***specific*** question along with whatever attempt(s) you've made.

Comment: please give a try if you can

Comment: No, I'm sorry, but you've come to the wrong place for that kind of help.

Comment: Hey @Aman, you are so close. Search for some html tags, such as [A](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) and [IMG](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp)

Answer (score -2):

I had some time to kill so here's one solution for your problem:

```
        const keys = ['Id', 'videoName', 'date', 'time', 'videoLink', 'image', 'videoDuration', 'liveStatus'];
    var tableBody = document.getElementById('myTableBody');

    fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/hy7g0').then(response => {
        return response.json().then(data => {
            buildTable(data.videoLectureListing);
        })
    });

    function buildTable(fullData) {
        if (fullData) {
            return fullData.forEach(videoData => {
                let newRow = buildRow(videoData);
                tableBody.appendChild(newRow)
            })
        }
    }

    function buildRow(videoData) {
        let newRow = document.createElement('tr');
        keys.forEach(key => {
            let domNode = undefined;
            if (key === 'videoLink') {
                domNode = buildAButton(videoData[key]);
            } else if (key === 'image') {
                domNode = buildAImage(videoData[key]);
            } else {
                domNode = videoData[key] ? videoData[key] : ' - ';
            }
            domNode = buildAColumn(domNode);
            newRow.appendChild(domNode);
        });
        return newRow;
    }

    function buildAButton(videoId) {
        let newButton = document.createElement('button');
        newButton.innerHTML = 'Watch';
        newButton.onClick = () => window.location.href = `url/path/${id}`;
        return newButton;
    }

    function buildAColumn(object) {
        let newColumn = document.createElement('td');
        if (typeof object === 'string') {
            newColumn.innerHTML = object;
        } else {
            newColumn.appendChild(object);
        }
        return newColumn;
    }

    function buildAImage(source) {
        let newImage = document.createElement('img');
        newImage.src = source;
        return newImage;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't provide answers to questions that don't belong here in the first place as it will just encourage more of the same.

Comment: I might do that but I have received so much help from this site that im trying to give it as much back as possible. I don't want to encourage people to make us do their job but I try to be as helpful as possible. 

But the code that i gave should be refactored. It can use switch() statement instead of if else structure. Function names are bad and comparisons with written strings and without constants is an bad idea. There is a lot of work left to do for Aman but this is a good wireframe how to achieve what he is looking for.

Cheers and have a nice day Scott!

Comment: We all can appreciate your desire to be helpful. But, in the end, we do have site guidelines that we try to follow to keep our site as helpful as possible. When we answer questions that don't belong here in the first place, we encourage more of those questions and before you know it, Stack Overflow isn't the high quality knowledge base that it's supposed to be.

Comment: @varjod Sir as i told i am new in programming so request you to put your code into my html code and paste.So  that when i run this page in browser it give desired result

Comment: I don't do that dear Aman :) You can try to figure it out because the code is quite self explanatory :)